# Define multiple URI for one <to .../> element with camel-spring

Tags: spring, apache-camel

Having an Apache Camel route defined in Java, I can do something like this

```
from("stream:in?promptMessage=Enter something: ")
  .loadBalance()
  .to("uria", "urib")
```

and it works like a charme.

Trying this using a Spring context file doesn't work out:

```
<c:camelContext id="defaultContext">
  <c:route id="defaultRoute">
    <c:from uri="stream:in?promptMessage=Enter something: "/>
    <c:loadBalance inheritErrorHandler="false">
      <c:to uri="uria, urib"/>
    </c:loadBalance>
    <c:to uri="stream:out"/>
  </c:route>
</c:camelContext>
```

Any idea, how i can set more than one uri per `<c:to ...` element? I do not want to have multiple `<c:to ...` elements. Is there any way, e.g. having a route factory passing the list?

What is the cause I want to achieve this: I'd like to inject a list of URIs from a configuration file passing them directly to the Camel route.

I'm using version 2.12.1 of Apache Camel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use a RouteBuilder class to create a route that reads URI's from somewhere.
2. Use contextScan to load the route builder class into spring camel context. Refer section Using [contextScan](http://camel.apache.org/spring.html) on apache's site.

The RouteBuilder class shall be

```
@Component
public class MyRoute extends SpringRouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        String URIs = // read all URI's from file or somewhere
        from("direct:start")
           .loadbalance()
           .to(URIs);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sry, I did not mention that I'd like to avoid having multiple <c:to elemets. Edited my question.

Comment: The easiest way shall be to write a [RouteBuilder](http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/builder/RouteBuilder.html) class and have your URI's read from somewhere. In the configure method you can build the route easily by passing the to method an array of URI's.                               `public void configure() throws Exception {  

  String[] URIs= // read the URI's from a file
  from("mock:a")
  .loadBalance()
  .to(URIs);
 }`

Comment: Ok, got it. Would it be possible to pass a route build by some RouteBuilder to a Spring Camel config config using a Camel element?

Comment: Yes it is possible. See section Using contextScan on [camel.apache.org](http://camel.apache.org/spring.html)

Comment: That's it. Tnx. Would you like to change your answer adding 1) Using RouteBuilder and 2) Use contextScan so I can accept your answer!